# Doubt in answer of simple combination problem

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> There are $N=4$ schools in a region, from which exactly $A=3$ will participate in an olympiad. There are $B=3$ students in each school and exactly $D=2$ students per school will participate. How many student selections can be made? [[Source](https://goo.gl/5MWdtY)]

We can use the multiplication rule. With repetitions (permutations):

- 3 from 4: $4×3×2=24$
- 2 from 3: $3×2=6$
- Overall: $24×6=144$

With no repetitions (combinations):

- 3 from 4: 4
- 2 from 3: 3
- Total: $4×3=12$

But the correct answer is 108. At which step am I making the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I think they mean $D$ students *from each school* will participate. So it is $\binom{N}{A} \binom{B}{D}^A = \binom{4}{3} \binom{3}{2}^3=4 \cdot 3^3=108$.

Comment: for (N,A,B,D)=(10,4,12,7) the given answer is 625817778 which is not divisible by (10 C 4 )

Comment: @shrey The numbers they report are the remainder after dividing by $10^9+7$...